# How to make a column flex have height: 100%?

Tags: google-chrome, css, flexbox

I'd like to make the following fill up the viewport vertically:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lkpKu

However, applying `height: 100%` to the outer div doesn't work so long as it has `display: flex`.

This was forked from:

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/qazmI

Which has no problem filling up the viewport horizontally.

Any way to accomplish this?  I'd be open to seeing hacks, but ideally this doesn't require that I e.g. manually implement the same effect using Javascript (which I know how to do and am not asking about).

I'm just interested in getting this working on the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add 100% height to html and body tag. `html, body{ height:100%;}`

Comment: html and body tag has inner content height is the default height. Check the [sample](http://tinkerbin.com/nv4OBmX6) it will solve our doubt.